# Exporting MS Project data to XML from Command Prompt

Tags: xml, command-line, ms-project

I'm trying to write a program that takes an MS Project file and dumps all the data to XML without launching the UI. I can't find any information on the the Microsoft site to tell me whether Project can accept arguments from the command prompt, like "winproj.exe FILE.mpp -export xml" or something like that.

Does anyone know whether Project takes any arguments like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work directly with Microsoft Project you probably want to look at Project's object model. I'd start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn175492.aspx, in particular look at `FileOpenEx` and `FileSaveAs`. The `Visible` property can be used to avoid showing the UI.

Alternatively you can use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) to read an MPP file and transform it to an XML file, which won't require Microsoft Project to be installed.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!